# How can I get text from inside a span element in selenium?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My code looks like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time as t

PATH = "D:\CDriver\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
website = "https://jobs.siemens.com/jobs?page=1"
driver.get(website)

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "_ngcontent-wfx-c163="""))
    )
    print(element.text)
except:
    driver.quit()

driver.quit()
```

Im trying to get the 6 numbers inside **span _ngcontent-wfx-c163="">215022</span** but cant seem to get it working, many others have had problems using span, but they have had a class inside it, mine doesnt.

How can I print the insides of the span tag that I have bolded?

Comment: Can you share HTML for that element in text format ?

Comment: It's unclear what element are you trying to catch? I see no element matching `_ngcontent-wfx-c163=""`  css selector

Comment: @Prophet  Hey sorry for not replying. p _ngcontent-wfx-c163="" tabindex="0" translate="" class="req-id ng-star-inserted"> Req ID: <span _ngcontent-wfx-c163="">215022</span></p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for **req.ID** to extract you can use the below **CSS_SELECTOR** :

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "p.req-id.ng-star-inserted>span"))
```

Note that there are 10 spans for `req ID`. you may use `find_elements` instead of `find_element` or probably `EC.presence_of_all_elements_located` which will give you list object. you can manipulate list as per your requirement.

read more about their difference [here](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/findelement-in-selenium)

Comment: Hey, if I try to use _of_all_elements and print the text out it will just close the website (obviously because of except: driver.quit() ). Im not an expert in Python or Selenium but how much more does the code need to be changed if I want to make it print all of the Req Id's since they all have the same "req-id ng-star-inserted" ?

Comment: not much change you'd have to do. `elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "p.req-id.ng-star-inserted>span"))` and then print this list. `for ele in elements:print(ele.text)`